# Published swf file not working as intended, but exe file does

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have written an application in Flash CS6 using Actionscript 3 that I intend to put on the web. I have a file upload function within the application that uses the UploadPostHelper class, which can be found [here](http://marstonstudio.com/2007/10/19/how-to-take-a-snapshot-of-a-flash-movie-and-automatically-upload-the-jpg-to-a-server-in-three-easy-steps/). I also use PNGEncoder and the flash.net library, as well as a few other sources.

Basically, the problem is this: when I publish the .fla file, I generate an .exe and a .swf. The .exe file will upload the file no problem, but the .swf file does not. It doesn't even appear to send the file to the server. I have enabled debugging on the published .swf, but I'm not sure how to debug from within the .swf application.

I have only tried launching the .swf file locally; I have not yet put it on the server. I noticed that there is a publishing setting for "local playback security". I have tried setting this to both "Access local files only" and "Access network only", as there is no option for allowing both. My concern with this is that it may need to access both, as it is converting the stage to a PNG image and sending that off to a server, does that qualify as local AND network access, as far as the local playback security sandbox is concerned?

Comment: You could post your solution as an answer and mark it as correct, might make it easier for others to find :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** I found the solution [here](http://mackys.livejournal.com/847749.html). Basically, I had to specifically allow the *debugger* version of the standalone flash player to access the C:\ drive on my system *as well as* the network. I did this by specifying "access network only" in the local playback security settings (under publish settings > Flash (.swf)), and I created a .cfg file under my "C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash\FlashPlayerTrust" directory, and wrote "C:\" in the first line of the file. This tells the debugger flash player that it can access anything on the C:\ drive. I also permitted debugging from the publish settings for the .swf file.

I hope this helps anyone else who runs up against this problem in the future.